# php webservice return array,but can't get the array from java client

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap

I wrote a php web service. The function is as follows:

```
function get_device_info(){
    $conn= mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "123456") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('devices',$conn);
    $sql="select id,description,hostname,status_rec_date,availability from host";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $host_msg[$i]=$myrow;
        $i++;
    }
   return $host_msg;
   mysql_close($conn);

}
```

Then I wrote the soap client in java to call this web service.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;  
import java.rmi.RemoteException;  
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;  
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;  
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;
public class javasoapclient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, MalformedURLException, RemoteException {  
        String serviceUrl = "http://192.168.1.44/webservices/serverSoap.php";  
        Service service = new Service();  
        Call call = (Call) service.createCall();  
        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(serviceUrl));  
        call.setOperationName("get_device_info");
        String reVal = call.invoke(new Object[] {}).toString();
        System.out.println(reVal);
    }
}
```

It can't get the array. I am a new in PHP. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance！

Comment: Please don't use the `MySQL_` functions, they are now deprecated. Consider using the `MySQLi_` functions or the `PDO_MySQL` class.

Comment: Can you include the SOAP response in your question?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

That is not how SOAP works. SOAP has a unique structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPrice>
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
  </m:GetStockPrice>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

What you are returning is just a simple array.

In order to get this array in java, you better use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)